# ImageViewPager Wrapping height dynamically according to the child image (view)

Tags: android, image, android-viewpager

Is there a way to dynamically set the ViewPager to wrap the child image just nice without leaving any space in between the height of the view pager and the top and bottom of the image?

I tried using the solution of https://gist.github.com/egslava/589b82a6add9c816a007

But the solution in the link only wraps all the images according to the height of the highest child view. Which makes every other smaller lower images look even flatter.

Is there a way to wrap the images according to each height of the child images? I don't mind the width being cropped off, I'm just more worried about the height. Some of my images fits perfectly without any loose spaces but there are a few which seems too flat in the view pager.

Hope to see your answers soon. Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0):

If it's white space you want to avoid why not try setting background to transparent.